# In StackExchange, how do I comment on other people's answers?

Tags: discussion, design, stackexchange

I cannot figure this out. I am trying to comment on answers and there is no option to. I have to admit, I don't think the UX design of stack exchange is very intuitive...

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is that you can't comment on other people's answers until you have enough points (50) to earn the privilege.  See the [Privileges page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) for more info, and be sure to review the [FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq).

You **can** comment on your own answers, your own questions and any answers to your own questions with only 1 reputation point.

Welcome to the community!

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! However, it is very confusing. Stackexchange should add the comment button but show the same warning box you get when you vote things up or down. Why allow you to find out you can't do something for some actions, and not allow you the same warning for others? I feel that this is purely illogical.

Comment: @AndrewDavis Or even, dare I say it, a poor user experience. ;) Seriously, +1 for exposing the link and either disabling it with a tooltip, or disabling it and putting "[needs 50 reputation]", or enabling it and then throwing an error dialog explaining why you can't comment.